# Is there a simple construction of a finite solvable group with a given derived length?

Tags: finite-groups, solvable-groups

Given some integer $n$, is there an easy way to construct a finite solvable group of derived length $n$?

It would seem that given a solvable group of length $n-1$, one should be able to form the semidirect product with a suitably chosen abelian subgroup of its automorphism group. But I don't see an easy way to ensure that the derived length actually increases this way.

Comment: It can be done with the wreath product...have you studied this beast?

Comment: Yes, I have seen those.

Comment: Well, then try to read here: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/245324/

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice way to do it.

Comment: It really is, and a nice exercise working out the details.

Comment: Actually, the proof @DonAntonio references is based on a proof in the wonderful book by John Rose, *A Course On Group Theory*.  There you take the wreath product with $C_2$ instead of $C_\infty$, so if your original group is finite, your new one is too.

Comment: @SteveD In the paper linked, the wreath product is taken with an arbitrary cyclic group. It is also interesting to note that this actually shows that the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{p^n}$ has derived length $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A handy example is provided by the group of $n \times n$ upper triangular unipotent matrices. If $n =2^{t-1}+1$, then its derived length is $t$.

Comment: Can you provide a proof or a link to a proof of this result, please?

Comment: I can see that the derived length is at most $t$. Is there an easy argument for why it is exactly $t$?

Comment: @DonAntonio see the reference on top of page 4 of http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sylow%20subgroups%20and%20the%20number%20of%20conjugacy&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CGgQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uv.es%2Famoquin%2F16.pdf&ei=-IMJUersNcWG4gSXvIDoBw&usg=AFQjCNGa9EgsqOh-h7wAoqYKRssaKtDErQ&sig2=hCQDyybHWdgF8wbmv93Q-A&bvm=bv.41642243,d.bGE

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AndreasCaranti . Huppert's first book in finite groups is imo one of the most important books that still waits to be translated into english (mainly to avoid those annoying germanic letters...yucks!), but it certainly has contributed a lot to enhance the skills in german language of many algebraists I know. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio, I completely agree, my copy is seriously worn out, but still precious. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio I agree. Maybe a collective effort should be put together to translate it (I would not mind translating some part of it).

Comment: I really wouldn't mind: my german is pretty weird but I can manage (the germans may have some tough time trying to understand me, though), but I think this then should be done  with the permits of both the author and the editorial house of the book (springer Verlag, what else?). I have no idea how to do such a thing...

Comment: I began such a project a long time ago, translating about 10 pages before giving up.  But I was using google translate and a minimal working knowledge of German.